# NSLayoutConstrains error occurs when reorder the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I set a simple cell in storyboard, 
[image]

Thers's a imageview and a label, I set some constrains, it's imageView's leading ,top and bottom space to contentview, and the imageView's width and height, and the label's horizontal spacing to imageview and vertically center to imageview.
[image]
When I run the app, it shows correct, no error occurs.
[image]

The rightBarButtonItem is the system edit button. When I reorder the cell, constrain error occurs, I do not know how to fix it.

```
2015-11-11 23:08:05.681 HiPDA[10108:2305919] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce60ce6cf0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fce60cac370(40)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce60ce6f10 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce60ca0610.topMargin == UIImageView:0x7fce60cac370.top>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce60ce7020 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce60ca0610.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7fce60cac370.bottom - 0.5>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce60c03a70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce60ca0610(56)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I was confused, when it showed, scrlled and removed, no errors occur, but when I reordered the cell, constrain error occurs, I do not know how to fix it. Thank you.

I upload the project, you can download here [download link](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1kTNaxSF)

There's are two navigation controllers, change the init controller between them, when the tableviewcell contains only label no error occurs, but when the tableviewcell contains imageview error occurs when reorder cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave imageView two Sets of constraints to determine it's height ,one is top&& bottom space, another is height.

When they conflicts with each other, you will get this alert.Change one of them to optional will fix the problem.

In you case ,You can change your imageView's height constraint from "=" to ">="  or lower height constraint's priority to 999.

Comment: This might give you a skewed image view since the height might grow or shrink and the width stays the same at 40. If you do this, then do an aspect ratio constraint to keep the image view to have equal height and width.

Comment: Yes, set the height priority to 999 solved my problem, thank you. I am also do not know why set the same constrains to label, everything is right, while   set them to imageview, error occurs as show in the project i uploaded.

Comment: @leizh00701 When you add subviews to viewController's view,the root view's size is fixed. But when you setted tableView's rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension,your tableviewcell's height is decided by it's subviews' constraints, and width equal to tableView's width.So you must use optional constraints to make it changable.If you want to fix imageView's size,you can change bottom constraint or top constraint to optional instead of imageView's  height.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. The problems happen may be when the cell is showed, consider the cell height is 56, the seperator line height is 0.5 in this cell, so the contentview of the cell is 55.5. When I reorder the cell, there's no seperator line, so the contentView is 56, so I have to make the imageView height to changable when the contentView's size changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your constraints the conflict is that

The imageview height is set to 40, it is pinned to the top and bottom of the cell, while the cell height is 56. how big do you want the imageview 40 or 56?

You can solve this by removing the top and bottom constraints and just do a center vertical to the cell constraint. i.e. ImageView.centerY = centerY

Here's modified constraints for your project on the image view 
[image]

Comment: not top and bottom, it's topMargin and bottomMargin

Comment: could you download the project and have a clearly look?

Comment: I have added a picture to the answer. The project named test had two tableview controllers: one had cell with label only and one had cell with image view only.  I modified the constraints on tvc with the image view only. If you want to add the label "username" then add a constraint on the label center  to  image view center

Comment: Yes, you did right. But I think I might add some other views to the cell and the cell's height might change as its subviews' size change. So I set the imageView's height, top and bottom space constrains to let the cell dynamically determing its size. I set the same constrains in label, everything is right, but set those constrains on imageview, error occurs. I do not know why